# A characterization of left ideals in the ring of n×n matrices over a division ring

Tags: linear-algebra, ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra

Please give me a solution for the following problem:
Let $D $ be a division ring and $n$ a positive integer. Then for each left ideal $I$ of $M_n (D) $, there are an invertible matrix $P$ and an integer $r$ with $0\leq r\leq n $ such that $I=PH_r(D)P^{-1} $ where $H_r(D)$ is the set of all matrices with zero in their jth column for all $0 <j\leq n $.

Comment: Should the very last $n$ be an $r$?